# Python Requests - Emulate Opening a Browser at Work

Tags: python, python-requests

At work, I sit behind a proxy. When I connect to the company WiFi and open up a browser, a pop-up box usually appears asking for my company credentials before it will let me navigate to any internal/external site.

I am using the Python Requests package to automate pulling data from an external site but am encountering a 401 error that is related to not having authenticated first. This happens when I don't authenticate first using the browser. If I authenticate first with the browser and then use Python requests then everything is fine and I'm able to navigate to any site.

My questions is how do I perform the work authentication part using Python? I want to be able to automate this process so that I can set a cron job that grabs data from an external source every night.

I've tried providing an blank URL:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('')
```

But requests.get() requires a properly structure URL. I want to be able to emulate as if I've opened up a browser and capturing the pop-up that asks for authentication. This does not rely on any URL being used.

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to capture the HTTP traffic that happens when you open the browser and authenticate with the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

From the `requests` [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```